# How to search a text or number in Multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am try to create a condition where condition should check the presence of locality or zip code in Multidimensional array, if any one condition is satisfied, its should return true or else false

here is the code i tried with a array

```
$cars = array("locationabc","locationdef","locationdghi");
$locality = "locationabc";
if ( in_array($locality, $cars) ) {
    echo "you can proceed service to your location";
    }else {
            echo "sorry we don't provide service to your location";
        }
```

but how to do that in multidimensional array, i don''t know whether the below condition is right or wrong

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("locationabc",500001),
  array("locationdef",500002),
  array("locationdghi",500003)
  );
$locality = "locationabc";

  if ( array_key_exists($locality, $cars) ) {
                echo "you can proceed service to your location";
            }else {
            echo "sorry we don't provide service to your location";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use following example to check whether value exist or not-**

```
$flag = 0;
  foreach($cars as $c)
  {
      if(in_array($locality,$c))
      {
          $flag = 1;
          break;
      }

  }

if($flag == 1)
    echo 'value exist';
else
    echo 'value does not exist';
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have multidimensional array as per the example you shown. You can do it like this

```
$cars = array
(
  array("locationabc",500001),
  array("locationdef",500002),
  array("locationdghi",500003)
);
$locality = "locationabc";

foreach($cars as $car){
    if ( in_array($locality, $car) ) {
        $msg = "you can proceed service to your location";
        break;
    }else {
        $msg = "sorry we don't provide service to your location";
    }
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: this the ouput for your code "you can proceed service to your locationsorry we don't provide service to your locationsorry we don't provide service to your location " it repeats 3 times

Comment: i am looking to check any one condidtion at a time locationabc or 500001